# 7.0.1 "No Accounts with iTunesConnect Access"

Tags: ios, xcode

Has anyone encountered the error that read "No Accounts with iTunesConnect Access" in Xcode 7.0.1?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 7.1.1 remedied the problem.